# 2 buttons click,1 in master another in content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Logout button in master page in my website.

Now i had made a content page belonging to master page, in that i have 1 textbox and 1 button. In this page i have done coding of search on a button click of a value written in textbox. but when i enter some text in a textbox and just make enter click it calls the logout button which is in master page.

I just want that when i write some text in textbox and press enter, it should call a button where the search coding is done.

Comment: Can you show us some code? Is this WebForms or MVC? Are you using a code-behind or are both buttons submit buttons within your main form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using normal ASP.NET, you can surround your textbox and button with a Panel. On that panel you can set the property "DefaultButton". Every control in this panel will trigger that DefaultButton when trying to submit form via the Enter keypress.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch" Text="" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use default panel. try this, I hope this will help you

```
 <div id="search">
    <asp:Panel ID="defaultpanel" runat="server">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch"  runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
  <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Go"  OnClick="btnSearch_Click"
                                TabIndex="0" />
        </asp:Panel>
```

and add the script as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('[id*=txtSearch]').keydown(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    //alert("jj");
    if (code === 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("[id*=btnSearch]").trigger('click');
    }         
});
        </script>
```